# Any Python memcached client that batches and parallelizes multiple get to multiple servers?

Tags: python, memcached, distributed, python-memcached

Very often I need to get the values for a long list of `N` keys such as

```
[1267, 56578, ... , 9800]
```

Those values are stored on `M` different [Memcached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached) servers.

I don't want to send out a `get()` request, wait for a response, and then repeat `N` times.

Is there any Python memcached clients that will let me call a single multiple_get for the entire list of `N` keys, split those keys into their respective servers, then send one batched request to each of the `M` servers, gather the results from all the servers, and doing all this in parallel?

If so, how do I use such a feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either *[python-memcached: Python](http://www.tummy.com/Community/software/python-memcached/)* or *[pylibmc  - Python client for memcached](http://sendapatch.se/projects/pylibmc/)*, both which has a `get_mult()` method for that purpose. That will cause the get operations to run asyncronously in parallell to each server.

See also *[Batch your requests with get_multi](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#Batch_your_requests_with_get_multi)*.